# DE10-Nano usb-blaster driver

Tags: intel, fpga

Has anyone been able to install the usb-blaster driver under Windows 10 64 bit?
The board enumerates but does not show up under 'Other devices' as it should.

Comment: Works for me without any problems. Just installed Quartus Prime web edition, connected the board, 2 devices appeared under "JTAG cables" section in Device Manager - "Altera USB-Blaster II (JTAG interface)" and "Altera USB-Blaster II (System Console interface)".

Comment: Did you connect it with mini-usb cable? Micro goes into hps, and not to the blaster side.